# Select rows with in particular range sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like below.

It Stores Students Details.

I want a sql query to have students Name who are between age 15 and 27.

```
CREATE TABLE Students(Sno       INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      Name      VARCHAR(255),
                      Age_Start INT,
                      Grade     VARCHAR(255));


INSERT INTO Students(Name, Age_Start, Grade)
              VALUES('Student 1', 10, 'Grade A'),
                    ('Student 2', 15, 'Grade B'),
                    ('Student 3', 18, 'Grade C'),
                    ('Student 4', 21, 'Grade D'),
                    ('Student 5', 24, 'Grade E'),
                    ('Student 5', 27, 'Grade F'),
                    ('Student 5', 30, 'Grade G');
```

Output

```
 
  Students Name
  Student 2
  Student 3
  Student 4
  Student 5
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct Name as `Students Name`
 from Students
where Age_Start between 15 and 27
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec34f/3)

Comment: there might be need of dictinct as per the data he is inserting

Answer (score 1):

```
Select distinct Name as `Students Name` 
from Students 
where Age_Start between 15 and 27
```