# How to select particular range of values in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

The following is my MySQL table. I want to select a particular range of values from my table `hello`.

```
name      age        job       gender

A         33         dgfd      m
b         44         gdfg      f
c         21         jhkh      m
e         23         etertr    m
```

How would I select a male whose age falls into the age category of 20-30 years.

```
SELECT hello.*
WHERE hello.age='20-30' AND hello.gender='m';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select rows with in particular range sql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794991/select-rows-with-in-particular-range-sql-query)

Comment: I've added an example with the age calculation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a `WHERE` clause to filter the data:

```
select name, age, job, gender
from hello
where age >=20
  and age <=30
  and gender = 'm'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16c15/1)

This can also be written using `BETWEEN`:

```
select name, age, job, gender
from hello
where age between 20 and 30
  and gender = 'm'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16c15/2).

Typically you will want to store a date of birth instead of the `age` of a person, then the age can be calculated when needed.

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT name
FROM hello
WHERE age BETWEEN 20 AND 30
  AND gender = 'm'
```

Don't store `age`. Store a date field and calculate the age. What would happen if the person got older?

Comment: I want to check age and gender and not the name.

Comment: @Ameer Confused by your statement that you wanted `c` and `e`

Comment: @Ameer Please make a new question if the requirements of your question have changed.

Comment: I've included an example with dates to show the age calculation so it adjusts for the changing ages from year-to-year.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM hello WHERE age>=20 AND age <=30 AND gender='m';`

Answer (score 0):

Because ages change from year-to-year you can do this.

Setup the table like this:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `hello` (
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `job` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` enum('m','f') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Values I'm using:

```
'A', '1980-08-04', 'clerk', 'm'
'B', '1969-10-12', 'waitress', 'f'
'C', '1992-09-16', 'pilot', 'm'
'd', '1991-02-21', 'unemployed', 'm'
```

SQL query:

```
select name,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,current_date) as age,job,gender from hello where birthdate > current_date - interval 30 YEAR and birthdate < current_date - interval 20 year;
```

Returned answers to the query

```
name    age     job          gender
C       20      pilot        m
d       22      unemployed   m
```

Added to SQLFiddle here.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0143c/1/0